# multiple-variable (2d) explorations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, data-analysis

Dears,

I have a project from Udacity "the Data Analyst Nanodegree" , in this project I am supposed to analyse and explore the IMDB data to answer a set of questions decided by me. it seems all the questions and analysis I have submitted are 1 dimensional (1d) or 1 variable data exploration, and one of the project requirements is to submit 1d and 2d data exploration.
therefore I need your kind support to understand multiple-variable (2d) explorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 variables (X and Y on graph), then you can use for example `jointplot` from `seaborn`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot(data=movies, x = 'CriticsRating', y = 'AudienceRating')
```

You need to provide more informations or paste part of the code so we can help better.